# Linux character type device driver , when the flush call will be made

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, kernel-module

I have a linux char device driver, In the log i could see the flush function calls being called in driver, though we never explicitly call the flush in the applictaion.

When the flush call would be called instead of release call. In what all scenarios the flush call would be auto triggered?

From the documentation we could understand

The flush operation is invoked when a process closes its copy of a file descriptor for a device; it should execute (and wait for) any outstanding operations on the device. This must not be confused with the fsync operation requested by user programs. Currently, flush is used only in the network file system (NFS) code. If flush is NULL, it is simply not invoked.

But want to understand in deep.
We use linux 2.6.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, the file object's flush method is invoked on *any and every* close(), the release method is invoked when the open file object's (FTE's) reference count drops to zero.

To understand this better, consider a scenario where a process opens a (device) file (for the first time) and subsequently calls fork().

Pseudocode:

```
int fd = open("/dev/xxxxx", O_...);
...
fork()
...
```

This will cause the Open File Descriptor Table's (OFDT's) ref count to remain 1 (as it's copied into the child process), but the FTE's ('open file' object - which it points to) ref count to be bumped up to 2, as both the parent and the child process now hold a reference to it.

If either of them now closes the file by calling

```
close(fd);
```

that process'es handle to the file will be shut down, the FTE reference count will decrement to 1 and the flush() method will be invoked by the kernel VFS! If the other process also  closes the file, the ref count will drop to zero, flush() *and* release() will now be invoked.
HTH.

Comment: To add when the child process exits also the flush()/ release() call would be made than calling explicitly close call on the driver handle.